# Not possible to create List of inner class with jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Is it not possible to create a list with an inner class with `Jackson`? The external class `Tradables` will work perfectly. But the inner class Underlyings will not work (Same of course if I make Tradables an inner class).

Is there a way to solve this without making every class that belong to an array of json objects be in it's own class?

Also it does not matter if the `JsonProperty` is above the set method. Any inner class that is not part of an array will also work.

```
private String sector_group;

    @JsonProperty("underlyings")
    private List<Underlyings> listUnderlyings;
    @JsonProperty("tradables")
    private List<Tradables> listTradables;


    public class Underlyings {
        private long instrument_id;
        private String symbol;
        private String isin_code;
        public long getInstrument_id() {
            return instrument_id;
        }
        public void setInstrument_id(long instrument_id) {
            this.instrument_id = instrument_id;
        }
        public String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }
        public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
        public String getIsin_code() {
            return isin_code;
        }
        public void setIsin_code(String isin_code) {
            this.isin_code = isin_code;
        }

    }
```

Mapping method

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            String json = RestLogin.getBaseResource()
                    .path("instruments").path("lookup").path("market_id_identifier").path(market_id + ":" + identifier)
                    .request(RestLogin.getResponsetype()).get(String.class);

            List<Instrument> tmpInstruments = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Instrument.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jackson and Inner Classes: yes, you can use, but they must be STATIC inner classes](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html)

Here's a snippet (but you should read the entire article for more explanation).

> If you do not add static, resulting class is generally useless for Jackson as well as any other data binding framework (Hibernate, JAXB); can often be serialized, but never serialized into

Comment: Very old article. I can use them without being static if they are not part of a list. Is this still valid for Jackson 2.6?

Comment: Yes it works :). I will look into annotations to avoid the static.

Comment: It will only work if dependency is direct, and not through `Collection`, array or `Map`. But I really would recommend just declaring inner class as `static` -- there are few upsides to using non-static inner classes.